# Calculating the sum of the product of two cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to do a calculation like this:

```
=(B3*I3)+(B4*I4)+(B5*I5)+(B6*I6)+(B7*I7)+ ... +(B57*I57)
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Any reason for the down votes on this? It's very clear what the question is here. Why are people voting to close? It's very easy to hide behind anonymity but no one learns from it.

Comment: I'm betting the `I tried a lot.` with no actual indication of what was tried is rubbing people the wrong way.  I know it irks me.

Comment: it sounds like you are looking for the `sumproduct` formula? `=SUMPRODUCT(B1:B3,I1:I3)`

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables (lol, love the name) the down votes for (unclear what you're asking) are just plain wrong then.

Comment: @Fogmeister - thanks!  no disagreeing here; I could see votes for "Too broad", but the "unclear" close vote is wrong and has pretty much become the "I don't care for this question" vote.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables My guess would be that it's a crusade against the "Fix My Excel" flood from office userland.

Answer (score 3):

I think this will work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B3:B57;I3:I57)
```

My Excel uses ";" but yours maybe use ",". Depends of the regional configuration of Windows.